# MySQL merge two columns in one whereby one column has a NULL value (and should be deleted)

Tags: mysql

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but when I use solutions such as `concat(column1, column2) as column3` then I get weird values.

My data is as follows:

```
Table1.Column1   Table2.Column2
A                NULL
B                NULL
NULL             C
NULL             D
E                NULL
```

Note: only 1 of the columns has a NULL value.

I want the following:

```
 Column3
  A   
  B   
  C
  D
  E
```

The property that one of the two columns have a NULL value will hold. It is just bad table / column design since it should've been one table and it isn't. I am not allowed to change the schema and I'm not allowed to insert/update values. I am only allowed to make a sensible query that retrieves the data in a sane way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to deal with the `NULL` values:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(Table1.Column1, ''), COALESCE(Table2.Column2, '') AS Column3
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement.

```
SELECT IF(Table1.Column1 IS NULL,Table1.Column1,Table2.Column1) as Val 
FROM Table1
...
```

Comment: Didn't try it but I could see this working too. Thanks :)